# Generating range of months using multi-level hierarchies

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

I want to filter the months of `[ComptaEcriture Date]` by selecting only the months from `[ComptaPlanId].[ComptaDateDebut]` to `[ComptaPlanId].[ComptaDateFin]`, but since 
`[ComptaDateDebut]` and `[ComptaDateFin]` are not from the same level and bot are not from the same dimension as `[ComptaEcriture Date].[ComptaEcriture Date].[Month]`, I don't know how to achieve that.

If I could generate a range of months that would be great. My dimensions are as follows:

[image: My dimensions]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're testing that PlanId is no the All member, you can use [isAll](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/IsAll.php) MDX+ function for this.

For the set, we will combine the [Filter function](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.php) with a [Declared function](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Declared%20Functions.php), even though we could put it all the code in the filter. It looks as :

```
WITH
  FUNCTION inRange(Value _date,Value _start, Value _end) AS _start <= _date AND _date <= _end
  SET myDates as  Filter( [Date].[Date].[Month] as t, inRange(t.current.key, DateTime(2015,6,1), DateTime(2017,1,1)  ) )
SELECT
 myDates on 0
FROM [Cube]
```

And using the compact and faster version :

```
SELECT
 Filter( [Date].[Date].[Month] as t, DateTime(2015,6,1) <= t.current.key AND t.current.key <= DateTime(2017,1,1) ) on 0
FROM [Cube]
```

Using the members :

```
WITH
  FUNCTION inRange(Value _date,Value _start, Value _end) AS _start <= _date AND _date <= _end
  SET myDates as  Filter( [Date].[Date].[Month] as t, 
                    inRange(t.current.key, [ComptaDateDebut].currentmember.key, [ComptaDateFin].currentmember.key  ) 
                  )
SELECT
 myDates on 0
FROM [Cube]
```

You can use [contextMember](https://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/ContextMember.php) instead of currentMember that check also in the slicer (FILTER BY or subselect)

Comment: Thanks, it's working except when I want to use  [ComptaDateDebut].currentmember.key. When I select a specific comptaPlanId (through a MDX fiilter in the report)  I can't retrieve correctly the corresponding ComptaDateDebut and ComptaDateFin members in another MDX filter of the report.

Comment: Try using ContextMember instead of currentMember (check documentation)